# How to round a user input in Java

Tags: java

I'm attempting to get a user input of a decimal, then round it to two decimal points. This is the code I currently have which is not working correctly, and I'm not sure why.

```
package code;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DecimalPlaces {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
        Scanner qweInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a decimal number:");
        String qwe1 = qweInput.next();
        df.format(qwe1);
        System.out.println(qwe1);
        }

}
```

Comment: ***is not working correctly*** what does that  exactly mean??

Comment: When I execute, I'm prompted to enter a decimal number, and after I enter it, nothing else happens, and I have to manually terminate.

Comment: You format the string but don't assign it to anything. Strings are immutable in Java, and cannot be modified like a list or array, so you must reassign it: `qwe1 = df.format(qwe1);`

Comment: why are you using strings? you should format them as floats and use the %2f format string for 2 decimal places

Comment: I tried this, and something does happen - an exception occurs. Why did you not mention this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With scanner, better use `nextLine()` when you can do it, it preserves from errors with the `return line char`:

```
String qwe1 = qweInput.nextLine();
```

Then you need to parse to `double`, because if not it tries to cast from `Object` to `double` and it crashes

```
df.format(Double.parseDouble(qwe1));
```

Then the `format` method return the string `formated`, because `String` are immutable, so you need to print direclty or save it :

```
qwe1 = df.format(Double.parseDouble(qwe1));
System.out.println(qwe1);
//----------------------------------OR----------------------------------
System.out.println(df.format(Double.parseDouble(qwe1)));
```

---

Edit : to avoid parsing to Double you can use nextDouble() from Scanner, as it it would direclty save as a double, but to save the format you would need another String so, with proper name ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`String qwe1 = qweInput.next();`

try

`double qwe1 = qweInput.nextDouble();`

By the way, `qwe1` is a terrible name for a variable! Variable names should reflect what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting the user input as a double and then do this:

```
double roundNum = Math.round(num * 100.0) / 100.0;
```